# Entity Framework creates underscore column when generating database

Tags: entity-framework

I have a simple object model as follows...

```
public class Product
{
    public long ProductId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Category
{
    public long CategoryId { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Generating the underlying database with EntityFramework results in the following schema...

**Products**

- ProductId
- CategoryId
- Category_CategoryId

**Categories**

- CategoryId

In the **Products** table, the **CategoryId** column is always set to 0 while the **Category_CategoryId** column contains the id of the category the product belongs to.

How do I cause the category id to be set in the **CategoryId** column and prevent the **Category_CategoryId** column from being generated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apply [ForeignKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute.aspx) attribute to `Category` OR `CategoryId` property. And change `CategoryId` property type to match `CategoryId` of `Category` class (both should be long or int).

```
public class Product
{
    public long ProductId { get; set; }
    public long CategoryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public long CategoryId { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

---

OR

```
public class Product
{
    public long ProductId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public long CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

---

You can do same via fluent mapping:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
        .HasRequired(p => p.Category)
        .WithMany(c => c.Products)
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.CategoryId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Great eyes!  The issue was actually that Category.CategoryId was a long while Product.CategoryId was an int.  Once I corrected the type so CategoryId was a long in both cases the schema generation worked as expected.

The ForeignKey attribute wasn't necessary.

Comment: What if you have a composite foreign-key?