# Invalid column name Entity Framework Column renamed

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm making an android app with `asp.net api` for the database. I got an error do something with the web service.

> An error has occurred
>   Invalid column name 'Location_Id'
>   Invalid column name 'ApplicationUser_Id'

I checked the migration and why I have `Location_Id` instead of `LocationId`? And `User_Id` too

```
 AddColumn("dbo.Locations", "Location_Id", c => c.Guid());
 DropColumn("dbo.Locations", "UserId");
 RenameIndex(table: "dbo.Locations", name: "IX_User_Id", newName: "IX_ApplicationUser_Id");
 RenameColumn(table: "dbo.Locations", name: "User_Id", newName: "ApplicationUser_Id");
 CreateIndex("dbo.Locations", "Location_Id");
 AddForeignKey("dbo.Locations", "Location_Id", "dbo.Locations", "Id");
```

In my domain I didn't type `LocationId` with underscore
Here are my Location domain:

```
 [MaxLength(50)]
 public string Name { get; set; }
 [MaxLength(150)]
 public string Address { get; set; }
 [MaxLength(250)]
 public string Description { get; set; }

 public Guid UserId { get; set; }
 public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

 public virtual ICollection<UserLocation> UserLocations { get; set; }
 public virtual ICollection<Storage> Storages { get; set; }
```

There's no Location_Id on my Locations. Only Id. I have no idea how to change the column in migration or entity framework. Someone can help?

Thanks :)

Comment: *why I have Location_Id* -- Because that's the default naming convention and you didn't override it in your mapping or data annotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you missed tables relationships setup via [ForeignKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) attribute or [fluent mapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591620%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). You can take a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729294/entity-framework-creates-underscore-column-when-generating-database) question, it could be helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

Its by convention that way but you can actually control it by using `[Table("MyTable")]` attribute for the table name and `[Column("ColumnName")]` attribute for column name.

Here is an example:

```
[Table("Affiliates")]
public class Affiliates
{
    [Column("AffiliateGUID")]
    public Guid AffiliateId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: where i should put it? on locations.cs?

Comment: @YeremiaDanang yes correct, name these accordingly and see if it works.